# Overload unsigned long in c++

Tags: c++, overloading, unsigned-integer

Is there a way to overload the built-in `unsigned long int` in c++ so as to automatically throw an error in case it has been assigned a negative value?

Comment: No, not really. Have a look at this library tho https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible to "overload" types. And there is no way to make assignment of negative value to `unsigned long` an error in standard C++.

That said, some compilers do provide an option to warn when they detect such case. `-Wsign-conversion` works in both Clang and GCC. Caveat is that it is quite typical to use negative values to initialise unsigned integers intentionally.

Something that you could do is define a class type that emulates integers, but potentially throws an exception in its assignment operator overload. Then use that class instead of the integer type.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Well, you cannot make an "integral" type. But you can make a class that emulates an integral type.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili No, enums aren't integral and enum classes won't even implicitly convert to/from integers, but point taken that class is not the only option

Comment: @eerorika thank you for pointing out. I remember reading somewhere "enums are user defined integer types". Perhaps I misremember.

Comment: @PeteBecker I suppose that class templates + template specialisations are sort of analogous for types, as function overloading is for functions. If you squint a bit.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure what I had in mind. (Comment deleted.)